# log onplay clicks into a database with multiple videos

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, video

I am trying to record the number of times a video is played and saving it into a database field on phpmyadmin to be used next time someone clicks the video, in order to keep a total number of times the video has been played. There are multiple videos on the page. Currently I can only get the first video to log a play count into the database.

Any ideas on how to select which video is clicked on instead of only working on the first one?

javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$VC1 = 0;  

const video = document.querySelector("video");
var a = $VC1;

console.log(video);

video.onplay = (event) => {

$videoName2 = $(video).attr("id");
console.log($videoName2);

  a++;  
  $a = a;  
  console.log($a);

                    var nameV=$videoName2;
                    var countN=$a;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'new-count-UPDATE.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                            nameV:nameV,
                            countNEW: countN
                        },
                        success:function(response){
                            // alert(response);
                        }
                    });
} </script>
```

php file

```
<?php

include("../db_conn.php");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

$nameVi = $_POST['nameV'];
$countNe = $_POST['countNEW'];
 

 echo "nameV:";
print_r($nameVi);
echo "  countN:";
print_r($countNe);


     $qry_stringVC = "select `videoName`, `videoCount` from `video-count` where `videoName` = ?";
     $prepVC = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_stringVC);  
     $prepVC->execute(array($nameVi)); 
     $resultVC = $prepVC->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $VCname = $resultVC['videoName'];
     $VCcount = $resultVC['videoCount'];
    
    $countNew2 = $countNe + $VCcount;
    
    echo "VCcount:";
    print_r($VCcount);
    echo "    NEW COUNT:";
    print_r($countNew2);
    
    $sql = "update `video-count` set `videoCount` = ? where `videoName` = ?";
    $qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
    $qc->execute(array($countNew2, $_POST['nameV']));
    echo "saved";
    
    ?>
```

video section of the file

```
<video class="spotted" id="simon-carina-chucky" controls><source src="images2/simon-carina-chucky.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

<video class="spotted" id="simon-from-3" controls><source src="images2/simon-from-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Comment: _"Currently I can only get the first video to log a play count into the database."_ - of course, because `querySelector` selects one single element only. You need to replace that with something like `querySelectorAll` - and then you will need to loop over the resulting elements.

Comment: Or - use _event delegation_.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried querySelectorAll and ended up with Nodes and then unsure where to go from there. How would I use event delegation?

Comment: Why this mixture of vanilla JS and jQuery to begin with? Use `$('video').on(...)`, and you don't need to loop anything yourself, jQuery will do it for you. And replace `$(video).attr("id")` with `$(this).attr("id")` inside your handler function.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't realize I was using a mixture of JavaScript methods. Do I remove const video = document.querySelector("video");
 and also video.onplay = (event) => {
And replace it with $('video').on ( code )??? Sorry I haven't used video.on before and not having much luck googling it haha

Comment: Documentation for jQuery's `on` is here, https://api.jquery.com/on/ The first parameter is the event name - without the `on` prefix. `$('video').on('play', function() {...});` would add a handler function for the play event, for all `video` elements that exist in the document at that point. And then inside that function, you can use `$(this)` to refer to the video element that the current event actually occurred on.